# Deploying a page built with vue-cli-build to Github pages is missing content

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, github-pages

I built my app with `vue-cli-service build` and then deployed to GitHub following [this guide](https://dev.to/rolanddoda/deploy-to-github-pages-like-a-pro-with-github-actions-4hdg).
But the only thing that appears on the page is the toolbar. The Vue components are missing from the v-content. This is what's rendered on the site where the content should be.

```
<main class="v-content" style="padding: 64px 0px 0px;" data-booted="true"><div class="v-content__wrap"></div></main>
```

[image: The content is empty]

No console errors as clues. I am wondering if I need to configure vue.config.js differently, or perhaps vue-router..

Here is my vue-config:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify',
  ],
  publicPath: '/my-gh-pages-site/',
};
```

Update: I was able to load the rest of the compnents by adding the correct `base` to vue-router like so:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  base: '/my-gh-pages-site/',
  routes,
});
```

The app is still failing to make some REST calls, which makes me suspicious that some of the javascript is missing.

Comment: Did you try this guide ~ https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#github-pages

Comment: I saw that and used the `publicPath` variable correctly. The site publishes, it's more that some of the sources seem absent.